# Is there an API that supports different Bitcoin wallets?

Tags: wallet, api

Is there an API that has sending and receiving functionality of different Bitcoin wallets such as Coinbase, Bitcoin wallet, etc...

Or would I have to manually incorporate each wallet API myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out about [Coinkite](https://coinkite.com/) after I posted this. I send an email to their support team asking:

"With this platform, will I be able to have a user link their wallet and be able so send bitcoins to another users wallet, regardless of what wallet they use?"

I got a response of "Yes" and they sent me a [link to their docs](https://docs.coinkite.com/api/index.html)